# Rails relationship based on common field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've found quite a few topics on `ActiveRecord` `has_many` relationships, but I haven't found exactly what I am looking for.

I've got two tables that each have the column xyz_id. This id is a corresponding ID in an API service I'm subscribed to.

I want to have a `has_many` relationship through these corresponding ids in the corresponding columns on each table. Such that, if an item in table_1 has an xyz_id of "abcdefg", I can do something like `table_1.relation` and it will return all elements in table_2 with a matching xyz_id.  I could leverage `ActiveRecord` throughout my code and utilize queries, but I think there has to be a better way.  Any thoughts?

EDIT: I a word.

Comment: I also realize that I could add a method on the model to allow for this, but ideally I would like this to come along with all of the rails relation magic that you get with the standard stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord lets you specify arbitrary fkeys when you define the relationship, like so:

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts, 
                          foreign_key: :xyz_id 
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies,
                          foreign_key: :xyz_id
end
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html